# How are $G$-modules and linear group actions different

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, representation-theory, group-actions

Let $M$ be an abelian group and let $G$ be a group acting on $M$ such that $M$ is a [$G$-operator group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_with_operators), i.e. we have for $u, v \in M$ and $g,h \in G$

(1) $u\cdot 1_G = u$

(2) $(ug)h = u(gh)$

(3) $(u+v)g = ug + vg$

If $M$ is also a $\mathbb F$-vector space, then we say that $G$ is a linear group action if also we have

(4) $(\lambda u)g = \lambda(ug)$

for $\lambda \in \mathbb F$ and $g \in G$, $u \in M$. In both cases, depending on context, we speak about [$G$-modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-module), this is also mentioned on the linked wikipedia-article. By $G$-module I mean here that only (1), (2) and (3) hold.

> Do you know any example where these notions are indeed different, i.e. an example where (1), (2) and (3) holds, but (4) fails?

I tried to deduce (4) somehow from the other, my approach: Let $M$ and $G$ be given such that only (1), (2) and (3) is true. Then we can extend this to an action of the group ring $\mathbb F[G]$ (the set of formal sums, or functions $G \to \mathbb F$) by defining
$$
 v \cdot \left( \sum_{a_g} a_g g \right) := \sum_{g\in G} a_g (vg)
$$
for $v \in M$. Here we have just used the action of $G$ on $M$ and that $V$ is a $\mathbb F$-vector space. Then we could embed $\mathbb F \cdot 1_G \subseteq \mathbb F[G]$ and by (1) the induced action of $\mathbb F$ in $\mathbb F[G]$ and the one already given coincide, as $\lambda v = v\lambda$ and
\begin{align*}
 \lambda v & = \lambda (v \cdot 1_G) & \mbox{by (1)} \\
           & = v \cdot (\lambda \cdot 1_G) & \mbox{Definition of extended action.} \\
\end{align*}
And taking this further (just a thought, the computations are actually wrong)
\begin{align*}
 (\lambda v) g & = (v(\lambda \cdot 1_G)) g & \mbox{by the above} \\
               & = v( (\lambda \cdot 1_G)g ) & \mbox{by (2)} \\
               & = v ( \lambda g ) & \mbox{computation in $\mathbb F[G]$}.
\end{align*}
Okay, the step in the second line was a little bit cheating, as (2) just holds for group elements, and not elements from $\mathbb F[G]$ as applied here. So this might not work and they are indeed different, but I cannot think of any examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $M=\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$ and $G$ a cyclic group of order two generated by $g$. Then there is an action of $G$ on $M$ where $g$ acts by complex conjugation, that satisfies (1)-(3), but not (4).