# Is the axiom $g1 = g$ essential for a group action

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

A group $G$ acts on a set $\Omega$ if

(1) $\omega\cdot 1_G = \omega$

(2) $(\omega \cdot g)\cdot h = \omega \cdot (gh)$

for all $\omega \in \Omega$ and $g,h \in G$. But is (1) really essential, what if we drop (1) and just require (2), then we must have
$$
 \omega\cdot 1_G = \omega \cdot (gg^{-1}) = (\omega\cdot g)\cdot g^{-1}
$$
for all $g \in G$.

> So do you know any example where (2) holds, but (1) fails?

Comment: Just a remark: how would you conclude that $(\omega\cdot g)\cdot g^{-1}=\omega$? Usually to prove that one uses the axiom $\omega \cdot 1=\omega$.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that axiom (2) alone tells you that the map
$$
\varphi : g \mapsto (\omega \mapsto \omega \cdot g)
$$
is a homomorphism of $G$ into the *semigroup* $M(\Omega)$ of maps on $\Omega$, i.e. $\varphi(g h) = \varphi(g) \circ \varphi(h)$. (Thanks to Derek Holt for correcting my previous mistake, I had written *monoid* instead of *semigroup*, of course a morphism of monoids takes $1$ to $1$.)

To get that $\varphi$ maps $G$ into the *group* $S(\Omega)$ of the permutations (bijective maps, invertible maps) on $\Omega$, you only need to require a single $\varphi(g_{0})$ to be bijective. Since this implies $\varphi(1) = 1$ (the latter being the identity of $S(\Omega)$), you might as well assume the latter, and this is axiom (1).

---

Proof of the claim. Suppose there is $g_{0} \in G$ such that $\varphi(g_{0})$ is invertible. Then axiom (2) implies that for each $g \in G$ we have
$$
\varphi(g) \circ \varphi(g^{-1} g_{0}) = \varphi(g_{0}),
\qquad
\varphi( g_{0} g^{-1}) \circ \varphi(g) = \varphi(g_{0}),
$$
so that $\varphi(g)$ is also invertible.

Comment: A minor technicality: Axiom (2) says that $\varphi$ is a semigroup homorphism from $G$ to $M(\Omega)$. Axiom (1) says that it is a also a monoid homomorphism. But a monoid homomorphism from a group to a group is also a group homomorphism. I prefer to define a group action as a (group or monoid) homomorphism $G \to {\rm Sym}(\Omega)$, but I guess that's a matter of taste.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you are perfectly right. Thanks. Fixing.

Comment: As to defining an action, I usually present the two equivalent definitions together, although the one with axioms (1) and (2) is the first to appear.

Comment: Why does $\varphi(g_0)$ is invertible already implies $\varphi(1) = 1$? We have $\varphi(1) = \varphi(g_0g_0^{-1}) = \varphi(g_0)\varphi(g_0^{-1})$, but we do not know that inversion commutes with $\varphi$, i.e. I do not see that $\varphi(g_0^{-1}) = \varphi(g_0)^{-1}$ is applicable here?

Comment: @stefan $\varphi(g_0) = \varphi(1g_0) = \varphi(1)\varphi(g_0) = \varphi(g_0)\varphi(1)$ so $\varphi(g_0)$ bijective implies $\varphi(1)=1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, a much slicker argument than mine.

Comment: @Stefan, $\varphi(g) \circ \varphi(g^{-1} g_{0}) = \varphi(g_{0})$ implies $\varphi(g) \circ (\varphi(g^{-1} g_{0}) \circ \varphi(g_{0})^{-1}) = 1$.

Answer (score 6):

Let $\Omega = \{1,2\}$, take $G$ to be any group and set $x \cdot g = 1$ for all $x \in \Omega$ and $g \in G$. Then of course $(x \cdot g) \cdot h = 1 \cdot h = 1 = x \cdot (gh)$, but $2 \cdot 1_G = 1 \neq 2$ .